# Upgrading KDE 4 to 5 on Debian

Tags: debian, kde4

I installed KDE onto a minimal Debian image using `apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop --no-install-recommends` but the desktop environment that launches when I run `startkde` is KDE 4. How can I update this to the latest KDE 5 version, which was my original intention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Debian [doesn't support KDE5 yet](https://www.kde.org/download/distributions.php). Try a [different distro](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/LiveImages).</s>

KDE5 is now [available in Stretch (Testing)](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/plasma-desktop). You could upgrade from Jessie to Stretch, or if you know what you're doing you could use [pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to get just the packages you want (though you'll probably end up upgrading quite a bit more than you'd expect).

Comment: OK. How come Kubuntu ships KDE 5 when it is Debian based?

Comment: Oh, I see... I know by doing so it would essentially become Kubuntu anyway but can I install the Kubuntu KDE desktop on Debian?

Comment: Looks like I'm off to Kubuntu then. I wanted to use Debian at first because I wanted a lightweight image without all the extra KDE software. Is this possible with Kubuntu?

Comment: Yes. I'm not a massive fan of this approach because it leaves behinds lots of packages that were originally dependencies for now-uninstalled packages and can't be removed using `apt-get autoremove` because they are recommended or suggested packages for other packages. But anyways... I'm sure it will work out. Thanks for all the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to testing (stretch) or unstable (sid) and you can upgrade to Kde 5 now.

I suggest not to do it now because, in my opinion, Kde 4 is much more mature and usable at this moment, and that not all from Kde 5 is available as Debian package. For example kontact, kwallet, ... are still used from Kde 4.

If I knew all of this I wouldn't upgrade to Kde 5 and I would wait a bit more.